# how to make HTTP/2 server push work with all directories in Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd.conf

How do I make server push header links work with all websites/apps regardless of where the file is located?

```
   Header add Link "</main.css>; rel=preload; as=style" 
Header add Link "</main.js>; rel=preload; as=script" 
Header add Link: </logo.png>; rel=preload; as=image;
```

Comment: Have the application do it?

Comment: what if I don't have control of the application?

Comment: Then how do you know what makes sense to be pushed?

Comment: only specific file types (css, js, jpeg )

Comment: so basically is there a way to check if these files are linked from any source?

Comment: You can't make a generic solution for something that is inherently application-specific.